# Why is Google Chrome handling touches differently than clicks with?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, printing

I am developing an internal-use application which requires the user to be able to print to a specified printer without selecting it in the print dialog.  To do this I am using [WebClientPrint for PHP](http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/) and it is working very well the way I have it configured UNTIL I use a touchscreen on Chrome.  I have also used Firefox and it works fine, but I need my users to use chrome for other reasons.

The way it works, is the app I am building has a button to print.  When the user clicks on that button, it fires some javascript that eventually executes:

```
$scope.jsWebClientPrint = function (sid, type) {
        var e_id = 'id_' + new Date().getTime();
        if (window.chrome) {
            console.log('hiay');
            $('body').append('<a id="' + e_id + '"></a>');
            $('#' + e_id).attr('href', 'webclientprint:http://192.168.2.69/hideout/scripts/receipt/print.php?clientPrint&sid=' + sid + '&type=' + type);
            document.getElementById(e_id).click();
        } else {
            $('body').append('<iframe name="' + e_id + '" id="' + e_id + '" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute" />');
            $('#' + e_id).attr('src', 'webclientprint:http://192.168.2.69/hideout/scripts/receipt/print.php?clientPrint&sid=' + sid + '&type=' + type)
        }
    };
```

What is crazy is that in the console, I can see that the call is being made to print.php and everything seems fine, but it will not call the WebClientPrint program to print anything.  When using a mouse, it works fine - when using touch it fails if I hit the print button too quickly (for instance if I wanted 2 receipts - it would make 2 calls but when using touch it only prints once).